# PHP find 28-character hex regex in string

Tags: php, regex, hex, preg-match

In a very long line, i need to find a regex that matches something like this:

`01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14`

now, that string is always made of hexadecimal characters, so it can be something like this also:

`ab ba 1a 2f 3c 2a 1d 35 32 12 34 78 90 11`

only thing that all of them have in common is that they come in 14-pair or 28 character hex values

How can it be done with PHP?

Have tried a few combinations, for example:

`preg_match('/[a-f0-9]{2}/i', $data, $matches);`

but none that covers all possibilities.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Have tried with a few* Show us your attempts!

Comment: ^ Put this into your question, there is an edit button

Comment: Thanks for the hint, did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a regex pattern that should match what you should need

```
(([a-f0-9]{2} ){27}|([a-f0-9]{2} ){13})[a-f0-9]{2}
```

[Example](http://regexr.com/3att4)